# Calling function design

Tags: c++

There is a simple design as below.

```
class A {
    public:
        void f1();
};


class B {
  public:
    A &a;
    B(A &a);
    void f2();
};


B::B(A &a): a(a) {
}

void A::f1() {
    std::cout << "f1" << std::endl;
    b.f2(); //****//
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b(a);

    b.a.f1();

    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to call the `f2` function in class B from the `f1` function in class A. 
How is it done in the most efficient way?

Comment: You have a circular dependency in your design.  There are ways to work around it but it may indicate that you should rethink your code's structure.

Comment: You're maybe thinking of some sort of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern ?

Comment: Or maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: @NathanOliver, where do you see any inheritance in this code?

Comment: Woops.  Somehow I though it was.  You need to either have a `B` member in `A`, for pass a `B` to `A::f1`

Comment: An `B` has a reference to an `A`. `A` does not have a reference to `B` so there is no way to access `B` from an `A`. You would have to register them both way, but this generally means your design is incorrect to begin with.

Comment: "There is a simple design" -- there's no design. How can you be talking about design when all you have is a made up code, and don't even describe the intentions?